# How to obtain the absolute position of text cursor in Visual Studio 2010 extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, envdte, vsix, visual-studio-extensions

I've developed an IntelliSense-like Dialog, which should appear on a specific key-stroke. (My project is a VS-Package, my dialog will be opened as a command)
The problem is, I don't know how to display my dialog at the **current cursor-position**. There are easy ways of dealing with the currently selected text, e.g. with

```
 TextSelection objSel = (EnvDTE.TextSelection)(dte.ActiveDocument.Selection);
```

but I can't obtain any absolute position here.

I've searched a lot, but didn't find anything, which could help me.
Maybe someone can give me a hint or - even better - code examples to solve my problem. I'd really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am doing exactly the same thing in a current project, so here is the relevant code copy and pasted. I generate the `activeWpfTextView` object elsewhere using the following answer: [Find an IVsTextView or IWpfTextView for a given ProjectItem, in VS 2010 RC extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413530/find-an-ivstextview-or-iwpftextview-for-a-given-projectitem-in-vs-2010-rc-exten).

```
    private IVsWindowFrame GetWindow()
    {
        // parent is the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ToolWindowPane
        //  containing this UserControl given in the constructor.
        var window = (ToolWindowPane)parent.GetIVsWindowPane();
        return (IVsWindowFrame)window.Frame;
    }

    private void DoShow()
    {
        var window = GetWindow();

        var textViewOrigin = (activeWpfTextView as UIElement).PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));

        var caretPos = activeWpfTextView.Caret.Position.BufferPosition;
        var charBounds = activeWpfTextView
            .GetTextViewLineContainingBufferPosition(caretPos)
            .GetCharacterBounds(caretPos);
        double textBottom = charBounds.Bottom;
        double textX = charBounds.Right;

        Guid guid = default(Guid);
        double newLeft = textViewOrigin.X + textX - activeWpfTextView.ViewportLeft;
        double newTop = textViewOrigin.Y + textBottom - activeWpfTextView.ViewportTop;
        window.SetFramePos(VSSETFRAMEPOS.SFP_fMove, ref guid,
            (int)newLeft, (int)newTop,
            0, 0);

        window.Show();
        resultsList.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: Added a comment in the code clarifying where `parent` came from.