# how to reset the Visual Studio editor Iwpfview

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

```
[ContentType("Code")]
[Export(typeof(IWpfTextViewCreationListener))]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Editable)]
internal sealed class TextViewCreationListener : IWpfTextViewCreationListener
{
    public void TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView)
    {
         ClassTemplateWriter.initializeFromParent(textView);
    }
}



public static void initializeMembers(string className)
{
     ClassTemplateWriterMembers.className = className;
     ClassTemplateWriterMembers.resetSnapshotLength();
     ClassTemplateWriterMembers.edit = ClassTemplateWriterMembers.view.TextBuffer.CreateEdit();
}
```

I'm trying to make a Visual Studio Extension adding code in the active document's editor(or buffer).
So far everything was good except,

I select file1 and run the command, select file2 and run the command there.
Now if I select the previous file and run the command the code is added in file1 not file2.

The problem is after the view for file1 and file2 is created using the TextViewCreate,
If I want to reset 'edit' with the active document's view, (using the function above 'initializeMembers')
ClassTemplateWriter's view member isn't the active document's view but the lastly created view.

How can I reset the member view with the active document's view?

(By active document I mean the document I'm currently running the command on. which is dte.ActiveDocument)

Comment: I really don't understand your question, or why you're trying to use a IWpfTextViewCreationListener at all.

Comment: I Need to use the text buffer in order to insert text in the editor. The only example I found on stack overflow was using IWpfTextViewCreationListener

Comment: You might be better off rephrasing your question to state your desired problem without necessarily pulling in whatever random bits you found, and we can go from there. If your real question is how to get an ITextBuffer for the active document, there's a number of questions already on stack overflow doing precisely that.

Comment: Could you please provide a demo via OneDrive, I’ll reproduce your issue on my side. 
In addition, If you want to  get Current ActiveDocument, please check the following solution 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163986/how-to-get-current-activedocument-in-visual-studio-extension-using-mef

Comment: A that's what I neede thanks starain. I'm fairly new to VS SDK and this stufd pretty complicated I didn't know what I had to ask. Thanks