# calling Roslyn from VSIX command

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn, vsix, vsx, visual-studio-package

What is best way to obtain Roslyn's SyntaxTree from EnvDTE.ProjectItem? I found some method for the other way (Roslyn's Document into ProjectItem).

I got VSIX command called from opened document and I'd like to experiment with Roslyn's syntax tree there.

This code works, but looks awkward to me:

```
    var pi = GetProjectItem();
    var piName = pi.get_FileNames(1);

    var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel));
    var workspace = componentModel.GetService<Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.VisualStudioWorkspace>();
    var ids = workspace.GetOpenDocumentIds();
    var id1 = ids.First(id => workspace.GetFilePath(id) == piName);

        Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution sln = workspace.CurrentSolution;
        var doc = sln.GetDocument(id1);
        //var w = await doc.GetSyntaxTreeAsync();
        Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxTree syntaxTree;
        if (doc.TryGetSyntaxTree(out syntaxTree))
```

Is there better way to get Roslyn's Document from active document?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use workspace.CurrentSolution.GetDocumentIdsWithFilePath() to get the DocumentId(s) matching a file path. From that you can get the document itself using workspace.CurrentSolution.GetDocument()

```
private Document GetActiveDocument()
{
    var dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
    var activeDocument = dte?.ActiveDocument;
    if (activeDocument == null) return null;

    var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel));
    var workspace = (Workspace) componentModel.GetService<VisualStudioWorkspace>();

    var documentid = workspace.CurrentSolution.GetDocumentIdsWithFilePath(activeDocument.FullName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (documentid == null) return null;

    return workspace.CurrentSolution.GetDocument(documentid);
}
```

Comment: The `.FirstOrDefault();` would not give you the document in the active context (in case of multi-target projects or shared projects).

Answer (score 8):

Frank's answer works great. I found it hard to figure out what the type-names are, so here's Frank's code with fully qualified typenames:

```
using System.Linq;

var dte = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
var activeDocument = dte?.ActiveDocument;
if (activeDocument != null)
{
    var componentModel = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.IComponentModel)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.SComponentModel));
    var workspace = (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace)componentModel.GetService<Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.VisualStudioWorkspace>();
    var documentId = workspace.CurrentSolution.GetDocumentIdsWithFilePath(activeDocument.FullName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (documentId != null)
    {
        var document = workspace.CurrentSolution.GetDocument(documentId);
    }
}
```

And here are the references to find those types:

- nuget: [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0/)
- nuget: [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis)
- nuget: [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageService](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices/)
- framework: EnvDTE (version 8.0, and set Embed Interop Types to false)
- framework: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost

I hope the two framework references can be replaced with NuGet references to [VSSDK.DTE](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VSSDK.DTE/) and [VSSDK.ComponentModelHost](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VSSDK.ComponentModelHost/), but when I tried, it gave build warnings about assembly version mismatches so I gave up.

Comment: The `.FirstOrDefault();` would not give you the document in the active context (in case of multi-target projects or shared projects).

Answer (score 1):

If you can figure out how to get from a `ProjectItem` to an editor `ITextSnapshot`, then it would be better to use `snapshot.AsText().GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges()`.

Note also that in your code above, by using `TryGetSyntaxTree` you are relying on someone else having requested the parse tree before you.

Comment: AsText extension method looks very useful. Unfortunatelly I didn't found a way to get that ITextSnapshot yet. Any clue?

Comment: found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413530/find-an-ivstextview-or-iwpftextview-for-a-given-projectitem-in-vs-2010-rc-exten)